# Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist while creating new actor

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Have below two entities with manytomany mapping and I want to save Actor with roles into DB for existing roles.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "actor")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Actor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long actorId;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "actor_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actorId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long roleId;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String roleName;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<Actor> actors;

    public Role(String roleName) {
        super();
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

}
```

When I tried creating a new Actor using JPA ActorRepository

```
final Actor actor = new Actor();
actor.setUsername(user.getUsername());
actor.setPassword("");
actor.setEmail(user.getUsername());
List<Role> newRoles = new ArrayList<>();
for (GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
    Role role = roleRepo.findByRoleName(authority.getAuthority());
    newRoles.add(role);
}
actor.setRoles(newRoles);
Actor savedActor = actorRepo.save(actor);
```

I am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.db.model.Role
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127)
```

Can you please help me with this, I am new to JPA.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep synchronized both sides of the relation. Currently you are using `EAGER` for `Actor.roles` but, when you get the `Role` using `findByRoleName`, the provided one does not contain the list of `Actors` (and you are not updating that one, I mean, `Role.actors`)

So, basically you have 2 options:

- Use `EAGER` in both sides. It has several performance problems.
- Be sure you will get the required entities with queries in both cases (using `JOIN FETCH`).

On the other hand, it is avisable use `Set` for such kinds of relations.
The following links will provide you more information:

[Link 1](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-many-to-many-mapping-example/)

[Link 2](https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-for-many-to-many-associations-with-hibernate-and-jpa/)